# How to print single value of dictionary in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary

I don't have much experience with Javascript and I'm trying to print a single value from a dictionary. My current code is:

```
    query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    res.success(results);
  }
```

the code returns the following:

```
{"result":[{"score":1337,"playerName":"Mr loba loba","cheatMode":false}]}
```

how can I only print the value of score?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `results.result[0].score`, assuming it's already parsed

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply

```
  alert(result[0].score);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your the return data is "data"

```
console.log('score', data.result[0].score);
```

To view in your browser's JavaScript console

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
console.log('score', results.result[0].score);
```